# CS-Cart Thumbnail Size not working

Tags: cs-cart

In CS-Cart 4.3.8 I have set thumbnail sizes under Settings > Thumbnails, then I have used the 'Clean up generated thumbnails' But nothing changes and they remain at the default size...

How can I set the thumbnail size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case you want to change thumbnail size in compact list you must tweak some code  in the "**compact_list.tpl**" file located in the **/design/themes/responsive/templates/blocks/list_templates/** directory of your CS-Cart.

Answer (score 0):

In Settings > Thumbnails there are some thumbnail settings.

You should change the relevant setting match to your view (Products list, Product detail, Product cart page, Quick View ...)

Comment: That's what I did, see question. This is specifically with the compact list, none of the settings change the size.